# Transparent logging of correlation / request id using reactor pattern in Java

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j, reactor

Question consists of two parts

1. What is the correct naming for this id. I see different names on the internet: correlation id, request id, transaction id.
   I will give an example to better describe what I am talking about, while I expect it to be pretty common and obvious case.

I want every log for an operation to be accompanied with unique id to be able to grep logs with this id and see every statement that is concerned to the operation.

```
class Controller {
  void process(Request request) {
    log.debug("{} Request accepted {}", id, request)
    Result result = service.process(request.data())
    log.debug("{} Request ended with {}", id, result)
  }
}

class Service {
  void process(Data data) {
    log.debug("{} Service started processing data {}", id, data);
    Result resultOne = repoOne.modify(data);
    log.debug("{} Repo one returned {}", id, resultOne);
    Result resultTwo = repoTwo.modify(data);
    log.debug("{} Repo two returned {}", id, resultTwo);
    return combinedResult(resultOne, resultTwo);
  }
}
```

And the log expected is to have same unique id on whole process

```
ABCDE-ID Request accepted WITH DATA
ABCDE-ID Service started processing DATA
ABCDE-ID Repo one returned SUCCESS
ABCDE-ID Repo two returned FAILURE
ABCDE-ID Request ended with FAILURE
```

2. How to transparently inject this id over the code in java if application is using reactor pattern?

In thread-per-request model it is possible to achieve this with MDC in log4j framework. In rector pattern different request are executed by same thread concurrently while waiting for io operations, so thread-local variables will not help.

The straightforward solution is to add id to every method as a parameter, but this looks ugly to me. I am looking for another solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you can ensure that call chain will be performed in the same `thread`, you can use `ThreadLocal` to store your correlation `id`.

In fact *Log4J MDC (Mapped Diagnostic Context)* feature, allow you to achieve that out of the box.

Comment: When using reactive programming one of the things you can't ensure is that all parts of a transaction will be performed in the same thread, so that's why a ThreadLocal based approach won't work in that case.